# + or - sign in array, C

Tags: c, arrays

So I just started learning about array and came across a question that requires me to print out an output of letter grades A, A+, A- etc.

However, I'm unsure of how to input the + or - sign into an array.
Here's my array line in question:

```
    char letter_grade[12] = {'F','D',"D+",'C',"C+","B-",'B',"B+","A-",'A',"A+",'\0'};
```

This warning came out when i compiled the code:
warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'char' with an expression of type 'char [3]' [-Wint-conversion]

Can anyone help me to improve the way i structure this part so that the warning doesn't appear? Thanks.

Comment: `"D+"` is not a *single char* (as well as `"C+"`, `"B-"` etc.)

Comment: `char` is one byte. How do you expect `"D+"` to be stored in one byte when it is more than one character wide?

Comment: You cannot mix `'F'` (`char` type) with `"D+"` (`const char *` type). Use string for everything.

Comment: @Crozin: the type of `"D+"` is `/*readonly*/char [3]`; there is no `string` type in C.

Comment: @pmg: Yes, at last someone has given the correct type. @everyoneelse, note well the `/*readonly*/` part.

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to do this in C is

```
const char *letter_grade[] = {"F", "D", "D+"/*, and so on*/};
```

rather than what you have. `"A-"` is a `char[3]` type, whereas `'F'` is a `char` type. You can't mix types like that in an array in C. But what I'm doing is relying on *pointer decay* to a `const char*` which is why the individual strings can have different lengths.

Notice how I've left the element count out of the declaration; the compiler will do that for you.

Comment: is this an array of string literals??

Comment: @popeye; you can think of it as being that but personally I don't find the term "string literal" particularly helpful in C.

Comment: so `letter_grade` is an array of type `char *` storing addresses (or pointing to) of each associative string constant...?? I'm slightly confused with pointers.....

Comment: @popeye: Each element of the array points to the 1st letter of a `0`-terminated `char`-array.

Comment: @popeye Yes, it is an array of pointers to string literals, each pointer pointing at the first letter of a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

A `char` is just that, a single *char*acter. As far as the C programming language is concerned, `char` is a numeric integer type, namely the shortest available integer type.

A string literal, i.e. things between double quotes, translate into something that behaves like an array of `char`s, either by being an actual array, or by degrading into a pointer with pointer arithmetic rules applied.

Which essentially means:

- the type of `"..."` degrades to `(char*)`, which is a pointer
- the type of `'.'` degraded to `(int)` which is an integer

Now in C pointers can be cast to integers and vice-versa, but this comes with a very strict and rigid set of rules, how these casts must be carried out to give sensible results. Trying to fit a string literal into a `char` sized integer surely doesn't fit those rules.

As to how to get around your grading problem? Make it an array of arrays of 3 chars, like that:

```
char letter_grade[12][3] = {"F","D","D+","C","C+","B-","B","B+","A-","A","A+","\0"}
```

Comment: The type of `'.'` is `int`, not `char`. And you mean `letter_grade[12][3]`. Also `"\0"` is `(char[2]){0,0}`; I prefer simply `""` (`(char[1]){0}`).

Comment: "integers" -> "certain integral types", just for clarity? Also the suffixed `"\0"` is probably of no use at all? (I shied away from mentioning that in my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this without changing anything else,

```
char *letter_grade[12] = {"F","D","D+","C","C+","B-","B","B+","A-","A","A+"};
```

Hope you got the answer...